# How load functions with same name

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm developing by Openui5 a portal. My portal have 2 apps. I I have organized the code in folders:

```
root
  |
  |____app1
  |____app2
```

In app1 folder I have util1.js with a function getInfo() and in app2 folter I have util2.js with function getInfo()   (same name).

Now my portal, at root login, load all js files in all subfolders, and only the last loaded getInfo() function work (correct???)

I think in the future to dynamically load the js file of appX only when the user enter in the appX.
In this way it work correctly??

Comment: So you are overwriting js functions. What was the question again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make your `getInfo` functions global. (This would be good advice even if you only had one of them, the global namespace is **very** crowded.)

Instead, ideally, have a single global for your portal's apps, perhaps called `Apps`, which is an object. Then have each app add itself to that object as a property, using the app's name. So:

`portal.js`:

```
var Apps = {};
```

`app1.js`:

```
Apps.App1 = {
    getInfo: function() {
        // ...
    },
    somethingElse: function() {
        // ...
    }
    // ...and so on...
};
```

`app2.js`:

```
Apps.App2 = {
    getInfo: function() {
        // ...
    },
    somethingElse: function() {
        // ...
    }
    // ...and so on...
};
```

Or you might go further and have an app registration function:

`portal.js`:

```
var MyPortal = {
    apps:     {},
    register: function(name, app) {
        if (this.apps.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            throw new Error("There is already an app called '" + name + "' registered.");
        }
        this.apps[name] = app;
    }
};
```

`app1.js`:

```
MyPortal.register("App1", {
    getInfo: function() {
        // ...
    },
    somethingElse: function() {
        // ...
    }
    // ...and so on...
});
```

`app2.js`:

```
MyPortal.registerApp("App2", {
    getInfo: function() {
        // ...
    },
    somethingElse: function() {
        // ...
    }
    // ...and so on...
});
```